# how to add space to the end of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string.

```
<span class="add">foo bar1</span>
```

Now I have to check the last character in this string.If the last character in this string is 1,add a space to the end of the string and move the cursor out of the span tag, Else if the last character in this string is not 1,just move the cursor out of the span and do not add a space.

So can anyone help me how it can be done in javascript.This will happen when I click a button 'Done'. I am quite new to stackoverflow.So if I made q mistake in the question,please forgive me.
Thanks

Comment: what "cursor" are you talking about?

Comment: Actually, this span is editable.

Comment: I am going to update my question to be more clear.

Comment: what do you mean by move the cursor out of the span?

Comment: This span is editable so it means I can write in it in browser.My question is if I click the 'Done' button,the cursor should be out of the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? This will loop through all elements with the tag

You should add an ID to the tag in HTML

```
<span class="add" id="test">foo bar1</span>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="addSpace()">Button</button>
```

Then use the following JS:

```
function addSpace() {
    var testElem = document.getElementById("test");
    var contents = testElem.innerHTML;
    if (contents.slice(-1) === "1") {
         testElem.innerHTML=testElem.innerHTML + "----";  
    }
}
```

I made a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nJeyz/2/

Comment: I think  this will add a space to the end if it finds 1 to be the last character.Actually this span is editable.So beside adding 1,I would also want the cursor to be out of this span.What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean the cursor out of the span? The code I put earlier was wrong so I edited it.

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct.Please consider this 


<span contenteditable="true" id="test">foo bar</span>

Can you do if I click the 'Done' button, The cursor should be out of  the span tag ? As you see this span is editable.

Comment: Edited it with a button and function. Remember to set as answer it answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the mouse of the user, that's impossible. However, you can revert focus to an arbitrary element instead.

```
<button onclick="mine()">Click</button>
<input id="testdiv">
<span id="test">foo bar1</span>

<script>
function mine() {
$string = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
if ($string.substring($string.length-1) == "1")   
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+= " ";
   document.getElementById('testdiv').focus();   
}
</script>
```